# Ubuntu server 20.04 in raspberry pi 3B+

Tags: server, raspberrypi

I have a raspberry pi 3B+ and I have installed this:
**ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-arm64.iso** file.I want to run a python program every day so I use the raspberry pi as a server for my app.I have tested my app in virtualbox using the same OS (ubuntu server 20.04) and the app is running as I expected,but I have a problem in the raspPi.
Output commands in rasPi:

1. arch -> armv71
2. getconf LONG_BIT -> 32
   So, I have a geckodriver file for 32 bit , I extract it and I move it to: /usr/local/bin and I give the command: PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver ,but when I 'm inside /usr/local/bin and I run the command: geckodriver --version ,I get the following error:
   ***bash: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error***
   I searched a lot but I can't figure it out.In the virtualbox,when I type geckodriver --version ,I get the version,but in the raspberry pi as I said I get that error.
   I also tried: chmod +x geckodriver,but this didn't solve it.
   What should I do?
   If you want more info, please tell me.
   Thanks.

Comment: You have a `geckodriver` built for some other architecture. `file geckodriver`, and `sudo lshw`. Also read `man readelf`.

Comment: where can I find the correct version of geckodriver for my raspberry pi?I have lost many days to solve this problem without any success